# How to upload a specific file to Google Colab?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I have a file on my computer that I want to upload to Google Colab. I know there are numerous ways to do this, including a

```
from google.colab import files
uploaded = files.upload()
```

or just uploading manually from the file system. But I want to upload that specific file without needing to choose that file myself.
Something like:

```
from google.colab import files
file_path = 'path/to/the/file'
files.upload(file_path)
```

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Providing a file path directly rather than clicking through the GUI for an upload requires access to your local machine's file system. However, when your run cell IPython magic commands such as `%pwd` in Google collab, you'll notice that the current working directory shown is that of the notebook environment - not that of your machine. The way to eschew the issue are as follows.

### 1. Local Runtime

Only [local runtimes](https://research.google.com/colaboratory/local-runtimes.html) via Jupyter seems to enable such access to the local file system. This necessitates the installation of `jupyterlab`, a Jupyter server extension for using a WebSocket, and launching a local server. See this [tutorial](https://robotwealth.com/how-to-connect-google-colab-to-a-local-jupyter-runtime/).

### 2. Google Drive

In case Google Drive is convenient, you can [upload files into Google Drive](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/manage-uploads#python) from your local machine without clicking through a GUI.

### 3. Embracing the GUI

If these options seem overkill, you, unfortunately, have to stick with

```
from google.colab import files
uploaded = files.upload()
```

as you alluded to.